# Why my text view doesn't change?

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

This code is supposed to suggest if the phone is charging or not in real time, changing a text view.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView testoStatoCarica;
String positivo = "Sto caricando";
String negativo = "Non in carica";
boolean variabileStato;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    testoStatoCarica = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TestoStatoCarica);


    //Ricevo lo stato di carica
    registerReceiver( null ,new IntentFilter("broadcastStato"));

    BroadcastReceiver ricettore =  new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle b1 = intent.getExtras();
            variabileStato = intent.getBooleanExtra("isCharging", isCharging);
        }
    };


}
}
```

And in the other class ( PowerConnectionReceiver ) i made this!

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
            status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    Intent i1 = new Intent("broadcastStato");
    i1.putExtra("isCharging", isCharging);
    Intent i2 = new Intent("broadcastTipo1");
    i2.putExtra("usbCharge", usbCharge);
    Intent i3 = new Intent("broadcastTipo2");
    i3.putExtra("acCharge", acCharge);

    context.sendBroadcast(i1);
    context.sendBroadcast(i2);
    context.sendBroadcast(i3);
}
}
```

Now,the problem is that i don't understand really what to do in my MainActivity with the booleand created in this last class! Anyone can help?

Comment: Please review http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and let us know what you expect the result of this code to be, along with what you're actually seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Monitoring the Battery Level and Charging State](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) article, it has code sample:

First you need to specify `BroadcastReceiver` in your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then, specify the `PowerConnectionReceiver`:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                            status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
    }
}
```

Now, the last step to pass new value from `PowerConnectionReceiver` to your `MainActivity`:
You can find the tutorial here: https://trinitytuts.com/pass-data-from-broadcast-receiver-to-activity-without-reopening-activity/

(Once you passed new value - you can update the `TextView`'s text)

That's it! I hope, it helps

Comment: @GabrieleRutigliano before you editted your comment, I managed to get what was wrong :-) you have to register to  `ricettore` , not `null`: `registerReceiver(ricettore ,new IntentFilter("broadcastStato")); `  (make sure, that `ricettore`  initialized